# Dirichlet Process, Stick breaking construction

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am trying to understand a proof of the following proposition:

**Proposition** Suppose $G$ is drawn from a *dirichlet process* $DP(\alpha, H)$, i.e for any arbitrary partition $\{A_1, ..., A_k\}$ of $\Theta$,
$ (G(A_1), ... G(A_r)) \sim Dir (\alpha H(A_1), ..., \alpha H(A_k)) $. Then G can be equivalently drawn from the stick breaking scheme.

In the proof the author makes use of the following construction without further elaboration.

"After drawing a sample $\theta$ form $G$, we consider the partition $\{\{\theta\}, \{ \theta^c \} \}$, we get,

$$ (G|\theta(\theta), G| \theta(\theta^c)) \sim Dir((\alpha + 1)\frac{\alpha H + \delta_{\theta}}{\alpha + 1}(\theta), (\alpha + 1) \frac{\alpha H + \delta_{\theta}}{\alpha + 1} (\theta^c)) $$

Hence, $ (G|\theta(\theta), G| \theta(\theta^c)) \sim Dir(1, \alpha) $"

This part is fine. However from here the author concludes that,

$$ G|\theta = \beta \delta_{\theta} + (1 - \beta) G^{'} $$

where $ G^{'}$ is the renormalized measure with the point mass removed and $ \beta \sim Beta(1, \alpha)$.

I don't understand why this decomposition is immediate.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\{\theta\}$ and $\{\theta\}^c$ are complementary sets, so they are a partition of the support. Earlier on in the notes you're reading they probably talked about the self similarity of the DP; that if you condition to be within a subset of the support you end up with another DP with a subset of the mass of the DP on the whole support.

So to think of what is happening with the $\delta_0$ "breaking off", you partition the support into two sets, because you have two sets you draw the probabilities from a Beta( not a Dirichlet), then you renormalize the non-atomic portion and start over again.

Comment: Specifically the self similarity stuff is on page 21 here:
http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~avdvaart/BNP/BNP.pdf

And he also has a proof of the stick breaking representation a few pages before if his notes can help elucidate it.